# Field is never assigned warning , using Webdriver PageFactory

Tags: c#, reflection, webdriver

I got warning message in Visual Studio 2010 : "Field is never assigned". 
I use Webdriver PageFactory that assigned field in runtime, how can i suppress this message?

here is sample of code:

```
public class VideoInfo
    {
        [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "detailsTitle")] 
        private IWebElement _videoInfoDetailsTitle; //Here is got the warning message

        public VideoInfo(IWebDriver webDriver)
        {
            PageFactory.InitElements(webDriver, this); //Assigen the field
        }
     }
```

Comment: You cannot "fix it" in your current set up. However, you can suppress the warning if you want :).

Comment: You are right, i edit my post :) 10x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's some voodoo going on that the compiler can't detect; you can just ignore the warning.  However, it's perhaps better to initialise the field explicitly:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "detailsTitle")]  
private IWebElement _videoInfoDetailsTitle = null;
```

Comment: add this under the using statement
**#pragma warning disable 649**

Answer (score 0):

Simple, the other way is you can change the access specifier to "public" to get rid of this warning

```
[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "detailsTitle")]
public IWebElement _videoInfoDetailsTitle;
```

Comment: While this gets rid of the warning, it also exposes the IWebElement to your test scripts, which is bad IMO. `protected` will get rid of the warning as well, but again that might not actually be what you want.

Comment: An alternative is to make it "protected". This hints that it's somehow being changed, while not exposing it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use property instead of fields, there warning is only about fields, there is no corresponding warning for properties, I don't know why but this solved the problem for me.

[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "detailsTitle")]
public IWebElement _videoInfoDetailsTitle {get;set;}